# What are the search engine affects of registering the same domain on multiple top level domains?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, bing, yahoo

I'm looking to register a few more domains for my company, I have my-company.com at the moment, but now require my-company.com.au and my-company.nl and others, for example `.ie`.

I'm running through my options and wondering what is the best.

1. Duplicate all the content on the .com package and make a replica at the other domains
2. Buy the other domains but do a 301 redirect back to the .com domain
3. Create a full new website with different content for the new domains, thus having no text duplication

We currently sell all over the world so would like to raise our search rankings in various countries. Can this be done by buying the domain in the country, and if so, how will the above methods affect our search rankings?

Any other suggestions are welcome!

Comment: See related (but not duplicate :o) questions,  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51304/multiple-domains-same-content and http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50115/will-having-a-website-duplicated-on-multiple-top-level-domains-be-penalised-by-s I think you are trying to do geo-targeting, which the three answers below describe quite well.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to rank well in each country's indexes, then having a local, and importantly a localised, site will help.

For that to work though each site will need to respond correctly on their domain, rather than 301 redirecting to .com.

More information on various techniques you can use can be found on [Multi-regional and multilingual sites](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en&ref_topic=2370587) on Google's webmasters support site.

Just duplicating the content on the domains will lead to various other problems, potentially including down ranking for duplicate content (manageable through use of canonical and href-lang alternate meta tags to tell Google which domain it should favour).

Answer (score 1):

Your first option is the best.  You should duplicate the same content across all the domains.  Then you should:

- make slight modifications for localized (localised ;-) spelling of some words.
- convert any prices into the local currency
- Use the local number format 35,000.00 vs 35000,00
- Change anything else such as shipping options that would be different in different places

Google allows duplicate content for localization purposes.  It does not penalize for such duplication, in fact it rewards it by ranking your local sites higher in local search.

There is a good answer that is worth your read on: [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Google official video with the answer
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ets7nHOV1Yo.

Option no.1  will be easy and cost effective for you and there is nothing to worry about duplicate content issue.

But:

1. Change the language manually not machine translation.
2. Change the valid currency if you are selling
3. local contact information & if possible then Register for Google Places for each site
4. Use all localized tags like `<META NAME="geo.country" CONTENT="GB"> <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="United Kingdom">`

Point is to prove that your country website belongs to that country and you will see that your country domains will get more targeted traffic than `.com` with less effort.